# JPA Define Projection for PostgreSQL Query with subquery inside or use anonymous result set to process data

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to get a set of Locations from my database and order them by distance from an location given as lat long input on my query.

The query is set this way:

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT * , point(?1, ?2) <@> (point(c.longitude, c.latitude)\\:\\:point) as distance FROM club_address c",nativeQuery = true)
    List<DistanceCalculatedClubAddress> getClubAddressClosestBy(double latitude, double longitude);
```

DistanceCalulatedClubAddress is basically the Location im trying to return (which is also linked to a oneToMany Relation) and the distance on top.

I tried using a projection, but I got as result the following error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type <MyClass>
```

which basically means Spring Boot doesnt know how to parse my query.

From what I found out, there is an ongoing bug in Spring with subqueries not being processable: [Projection fails when using subquery - Spring Data JPA](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2008)

and I think this might me affect too - so Im kinda tapping in the dark where to go on from here. My best guess is to use anonymous return values and parse them manually (something like ResultSet in java sql).

How can I process the results of this query like this mostly with the benefits of Spring JPA?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was stupidly easy: First of all i had to rename my value "clubAddress" to "club_address" , then my projection worked as intended. So Projections are the way to go, i simply had to rename it. If you want to test it simply return on you Query objects instead of your class and check how they are named. Then match them accordingly.